# getting output of union all without using union all

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have been given a situation to find the common record between 2 tables without using `union`. I could do it. But I am not able to do 'union all'. I mean I have to find out output of 2 table including duplicate without using `union all`. is there anyway to do it?

```
table A has x column and values 1,2,3 
     and
table B has x column and values 3,4,5

select x from A union select x from B;
o/p 1,2,3,4,5

select x from A union all select x from B;
o/p should be 1,2,3,3,4,5,6(not necessarily in order)
```

`Union` output I can achieve through below query

```
select nvl(a.x,b.x) output from A full outer join B on A.x=b.X order by output;
```

but I am not able to do `union all` without using oracle inbuilt `union all`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Explain why you cannot use `union all`

Comment: _Common_, does that really mean rows that exist only in one of the tables?

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results. It could also be helpful to show us your existing query, that works for `union`.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff this was interview question of amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get *plus points* in the interview if you mention some *edge cases*, here it could be:

**Primary Key**

If the column in one of the tables is not a *primary key* (or at leadt unique) the proposed solution for `UNION`

```
select nvl(a.x,b.x) output from A full outer join B on A.x=b.X
```

*fails* and you have to use `DISTINCT`

```
select distinct  nvl(a.x,b.x) output from A full outer join B on A.x=b.X
```

**Nullable Column**

If the column in one of the tables is *nullable* the proposed solution for `UNION ALL`

```
select nvl(a.x, b.x) x from a full join b on a.x is null or b.x is null
```

*fails*. The other solution with `on 1=2` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are too close to your answer.

For `union`, you used following query where you have a join on column x:

```
select nvl(a.x,b.x) output from A full outer join B on A.x=b.X order by output;
```

For `union all`, you can use join condition which can never be satisfied. It will generate same output as `union all`.

So you must use following query:

> ```
> select nvl(a.x,b.x) output from A full outer join B on 1=2 order by output;
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

> I have to find out output of 2 table including duplicate without using
>   `union all`

```
select nvl(a.x, b.x) x from a full join b on a.x is null or b.x is null
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=353df0e152abeabb0f26600a95f07b25)</sup>**